# how to use lodash filter function using variable

Tags: lodash

I am using lodash in one of my projects to achieve filter. My requirement is we have different SELECT options that are generated dynamically. And these are populated with json.
    So my filter function that I need should be generic. For example if there are 3 drop downs.

dropdown1. populated with values whose json_property is ABC_CODE="002"
dropdown2. populated with values whose json_property is xyz_CODE="002"

dropdown2 values should change based on dropdown1 selection

I have a masterdata list, which tells this information.

The loadash `_.filter` function should use varaibles. Because this filter should be used dynamically for different select options.

ex:

```
var a=_.filter($scope.masterData, function(e){
    return _.indexOf(v, e.ABC_CODE) != -1;
});
console.log(a); //returns array of objects
```

I get the values.
How can I replace ABC_CODE from a javascript variable. like e.tempVar where tempVar is ABC_CODE

Answer (score 0):

use bracket notation

```
var a = _.filter($scope.masterData, function(e) {
    var key = ABC_CODE;
    return _.indexOf(v, e[key]) != -1;
});
console.log(a); //returns array of objects
```

Comment: @user1015388 please accept if it answered your question